# Angular 6: using date format pipe with async

Tags: angular

In my Angular 6 component, I have a property of type `Observable<string>` like this:

```
dateFormat$: Observable<string>;
```

In the template, I am binding `dateFormat$` to set the format of the date using `async` pipe:

```
<span>{{data[date.field] | date:(dateFormat$ | async)}}</span>
```

But during build, I am getting the build error:

> Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'string | undefined'. Type 'Observable' is not
>   assignable to type 'string'.

What could be the possible reason of this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: which means your pipe expecting string value not an observable

Comment: {{ data[date.field] | async | date: dateFormat$ }}

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `<span *ngIf="dateFormat$ | async as dateFormat">{{data[date.field] | date:dateFormat}}</span>`

Comment: Did try that, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm later, but this answer may help others. I was trying to get a formatted value of async observable, but I had a similar problem then you. So I solved my problem by creating a function to get the async value from a BehaviorSubject and in this function the formatted the data.

`value$: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>(99.01);

<span>{{ format(value$) }}</span> 
       <!-- R$ 99,01 -->

format(observable: BehaviorSubject<number>) {
   const frmt = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
   return frmt.format(observable.getValue());
}`

This may resolve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a default value like the one below.

based on the Observable i'm passing here as an empty string as ''

{{data[date.field] | async)??'' | pipename}}